# Rewrite requests to a directory (w/o a trailing slash) to index.php in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen similar requests for this but was not able to find a hard and fast answer that worked. Essentially I want to internally rewrite requests to a directory (where the requested URL does NOT contain a trailing slash) to the index.php contained in that directory:

```
http://example.com/foo => http://example.com/foo/index.php
```

Right now if a request is made to http://example.com/foo apache will do an externally visible 301 redirect to http://example.com/foo/, which in turn will result in the index.php being rendered, but I want to avoid this external redirect and extra request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
DirectorySlash On
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule (?!^.+?/$)^(.+)$ /$1/index.php [L]
```